# Accessing variables after dynamically loading a script

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Right up front:  this project doesn't use JQuery.

We have some third-party JavaScript; it's big and hairy and doesn't need to be used often, so we're dynamically loading it only when we need to:

```
function loadBigHairyCode()
{
    var file = document.createElement('script')
    file.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
    file.setAttribute("src","path/to/big/ugly/script/file.js")
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(file)

    magic_needs_to_happen_here
}
```

The script loading works fine, including some corresponding CSS that's not shown here.

The loaded file defines a constructor function (call it `UglyGlobalFunc`) which we use elsewhere in the usual way (`var foo = new UglyGlobalFunc(....)`).  The problem is, because the rest of that file is kinda ugly, we need to fix it up a bit so that it sucks less.  Specifically, at the point where I've shown "magic needs to happen here" above, I want to write the equivalent of

```
UglyGlobalFunc.prototype.BodgeBodgeBodge = function() {....}
```

just as if I were editing the underlying file.

But that fails, because at that point in the code, UglyGlobalFunc is undefined, which makes sense.  Same for a simple level of indirection like `window.UglyGlobalFunc.proto...`.  So my questions are:

1. Are the dynamically loaded contents even accessible at that point of execution (where magic needs to happen)?  Or do they not become "real" until after `loadBigHairyCode()` returns and the browser goes through some kind of refresh cycle?
2. If yes, then how do I access them?  Some kind of `getGlobalVariableByName("string")` function?
3. If not, then... aieee.  How do normal sane people go about doing that kind of thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this

```
function loadBigHairyCode()
{
    var file = document.createElement('script')
    file.onreadystatechange= function () { // works in IE
        if (this.readyState == 'complete') MyFunc();
    }
    file.onload= MyFunc;
    file.type="text/javascript";
    file.src="path/to/big/ugly/script/file.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(file)
}

function MyFunc(){
    //....
}
```

**Update:** [**You may read this**](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/23/loading-javascript-without-blocking/).

Comment: Yep, looks better now : ). I'll remove my previous comment, it's irrelevant now.

Comment: @Teemu, This way the script doesn't block page loading, called `async`.

Answer (score 3):

When you create a `<script>` element like that, you have to bind to its `onload` event, which is fired as soon as it's loaded and available for use.

Another option is to just use `document.write('<script src="..."></script>');` to have it loaded synchronously. Then you can use it in the following line. Just make sure to do that *before* the page finishes loading, or your whole document will be overwritten.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that individual script elements could even HAVE their own events like that.  (I am not a web guy.)  Thanks to everyone who answered!

Comment: @TiStrga `<img>` elements have that event too (might be useful).